# How to make a python code start at a certain point after its done, without starting the entire code again?

Tags: python

```
import random
import time
```

#input

I'd like to start the script from here again

```
answer=random.randint(1,10)

print("The answer comes after you have used all your tries")

guessone=int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10:"))
guesstwo=int(input("four chances left:"))
guessthree=int(input("Three chances left:"))
guessfour=int(input("Two chances left:"))
guessfive=int(input("Last chance:"))
```

#output

```
if guessone == answer:
    print("Congratulations, you guess right")
elif guesstwo == answer:
    print("Congratulations, you guess right")
elif guessthree == answer:
    print("Congratulations, you guess right")
elif guessfour == answer:
    print("Congratulations, you guess right")
elif guessfive == answer:
    print("Congratulations, you guess right")

else:
    print("You guessed wrong")

print("The answer is", answer)

time.sleep(5)
```

I'd like to start it again 5 secs. after the answer comes forth

Comment: ... Are you asking about loops?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a loop, like so:

```
while (True):
    answer=random.randint(1,10)

    print("The answer comes after you have used all your tries")

    guessone=int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10:"))
    guesstwo=int(input("four chances left:"))
    guessthree=int(input("Three chances left:"))
    guessfour=int(input("Two chances left:"))
    guessfive=int(input("Last chance:"))

    if guessone == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guesstwo == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guessthree == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guessfour == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guessfive == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")

    else:
        print("You guessed wrong")

    print("The answer is", answer)

    time.sleep(5)
```

Of course, this will loop forever. If you want to be able to exit your program, you will need to replace `True` with a condition, for instance checking for a certain input.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow.

What you've got there is a fine example of how not to write code :P

Things that will help you are functions. You put the thing you want to do repeatedly in such a function and then just call it again later.

You furthermore could use a loop which just calls the function again and again.
if you'd insert a time.sleep(5) call then, you'd be done.

You'll likely figure this out on your own :)

**If you don't want to figure this out, here is your solution**

This will loop through your quetionaire and do something useful around it, like keeoing track of the score.

```
import random
import time

#input

# You can now start the script from here again
def questionaire():
    answer=random.randint(1,10)

    print("The answer comes after you have used all your tries")

    guessone=int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10:"))
    guesstwo=int(input("four chances left:"))
    guessthree=int(input("Three chances left:"))
    guessfour=int(input("Two chances left:"))
    guessfive=int(input("Last chance:"))

    #output

    if guessone == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guesstwo == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guessthree == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guessfour == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")
    elif guessfive == answer:
        print("Congratulations, you guess right")

    else:
        print("You guessed wrong")
        return False

    print("The answer is", answer)
    return True

score = 0
while True: 
    score+= 1 if questionaire() else 0
    print("Your score is currently {}".format(score))
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25528942)

Comment: I'm not critizizing his question style, but his style of code. I don't expect him to alter his question, as I understood him quite well. But I am not willing to give him a running code example for his relative low effort (every basic python tutorial covers what I mentioned) and therefore only gave him the right words to look for on his next google search. With what I gave him he should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I don't agree, but I'll update it. I don't think it's better to give him working code.